# Operator overloading += to add new object

Tags: c++

Learning operator overloading in this project, and below in the `ship.cpp` file is where I think my error is.

This is the test file, I cannot change this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "Ship.h"
#include "Engine.h"
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;

void printHeader(const char* title)
{
    char oldFill = cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "|> " << title << endl;

    cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout.fill(oldFill);
}

int main()
{
    {
        printHeader("T1: Testing Constants");

        cout << "TYPE_MAX_SIZE: " << sdds::TYPE_MAX_SIZE << endl;
        cout << "MIN_STD_POWER: " << sdds::MIN_STD_POWER << endl;
        cout << "MAX_STD_POWER: " << sdds::MAX_STD_POWER << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T2: Testing Default Constructor");

        Ship invalid;
        invalid.display();
        invalid += Engine("D2", 2.1);
        cout << endl;
    }

    Engine engines[] = {
        Engine("V8", 4.4),
        Engine("V8", 5.0),
        Engine("Inline", 4.1),
        Engine("D3", 7.0),
        Engine("D0", 2.0),
        Engine("D1", 3.2),
    };

    {
        printHeader("T3: Testing Custom Constructor");
        
        Ship titanic("cruiser", engines, 6);
        titanic.display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T4: Testing Conversion to Bool Operator");
        Ship invalid;
        Ship titanic("liner", engines, 1);

        if (invalid)
            cout << "1. Test Failed! Object should be invalid.\n";
        else
            cout << "1. Test succeeded!\n";

        if (titanic)
            cout << "2. Test succeeded!\n";
        else
            cout << "3. Test Failed! Object should be valid.\n";
        
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T5: Testing += and < Operators");

        Ship titanic("liner", engines, 3);

        char type[]{ "D0" };
        while (titanic < sdds::MIN_STD_POWER)
        {
            type[1]++;
            cout << "Ship not up to standard. Required power: "
                 << sdds::MIN_STD_POWER << endl;
            titanic += Engine(type, 2.1);
        }

        titanic.display();

        if (sdds::MAX_STD_POWER < titanic)
            cout << "Too much power." << endl;
        else
            cout << "Ship doesn't exceed power regulation of: "
                 << sdds::MAX_STD_POWER << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my `Ship.cpp` file. My error is in the `+=` operator function, where I have to add an engine but don't understand how I should approach it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Ship.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sdds {

Ship::Ship(){
    m_type[0] = '\0';
    m_engCnt = 0;
}

Ship::Ship(const char* type, const Engine engines[], int cnt){
    if (type != nullptr && engines != nullptr && cnt > 0) {
        // create a valid ship
        strncpy(m_type, type, TYPE_MAX_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            m_engines[i] = engines[i];
        }
        m_engCnt = cnt;
        
    }else{
        m_type[0] = '\0';
        m_engCnt = 0;
    }
}

Ship::operator bool() const {
    // return true if the ship is valid (not empty)
    if(m_type[0] == '\0' || m_engCnt == 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

Ship& Ship::operator+=(Engine e){
    if (!*this) {
        cout << "The Object is not valid! Engine cannot be added!" << endl;
        return *this;
    }else if (m_engCnt == NUM_OF_ENGINES){
        return *this;
    }else{
        // ERROR I BELIEVE IS HERE --> I dont understand the syntax to add engine here
        m_engCnt++;
        return *this;
    }
    
}

double Ship::calculatePower() const {
    double power = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_engCnt; i++) {
        power += m_engines[i].get() * 5;
    }
    return power;
}

void Ship::display()const{
    if (*this) {
        cout << m_type << " - " << calculatePower() << endl;
        Engine e;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_engCnt; i++) {
            m_engines[i].display();
            
        }
    }else{
        cout << "No available data" << endl;
    }
}
bool Ship::operator<(double power) const{
    if (calculatePower() < power) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator<(double power, const Ship& theShip){
    if (power < theShip.calculatePower()) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This is my `engine.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Engine.h"
using namespace sdds;
using namespace std;

namespace sdds {
Engine::Engine(){
    m_type[0] = '\0';
    m_size = 0.0;
}

Engine::Engine(const char* type, double size){
    strncpy(m_type, type, TYPE_MAX_SIZE);
    m_size = size;
}

double Engine::get() const{
    return m_size;
}

void Engine::display() const{
    cout << m_size << " liters - " << m_type << endl;
    
}
}
```

This should be the output, but my function is stuck in the `while` loop:

```
|> T5: Testing += and < Operators
----------------------------------------
Ship not up to standard. Required power: 90.111
Ship not up to standard. Required power: 90.111
Ship not up to standard. Required power: 90.111
liner - 99
4.4 liters - V8
5 liters - V8
4.1 liters - Inline
2.1 liters - D1
2.1 liters - D2
2.1 liters - D3
Ship doesn't exceed power regulation of: 99.999
```

Comment: Is your `Ship` class contains some sort of list of engine like a `std::vector<Engine>`? Without the relevant parts inside `Ship` it would be hard to help

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs Without seeing what your `operator!` and `operator<` implementations are looking for, it is really hard to know why your `operator+=` is not working as expected. Also, what is the point of passing parameter to `Engine` if `operator+=` is not going to use them? Maybe that is the root of your problem?

Comment: added the list of engines they are in main files aswell @GuillaumeRacicot

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs You havne't shown what `calculatePower()` does, or how the `Ship` constructor is using that array of `Engine`s. Presumably the constructor is doing something with each `Engine` that your `operator+=` is not doing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the Parameters to the engine is provided by in the test file, I cannot change that. @RemyLebeau

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs that did not answer my questions at all.  I'm assuming an `Engine` has a power level that contributes to a `Ship`'s total power. Your `operator<` are looking for that level, but your `operator+=` is ignoring it. Does the `Ship` constructor also ignore it? Please show the `Ship` constructor, and `calculatePower()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the entire file.

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs Now we are finally getting somewhere. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator+=` is not doing anything with the `Engine` that is passed to it.  Your `Ship` class has an `m_engines` array, which your `Ship` constructor adds `Engine`s to (without regard to `NUM_OF_ENGINES`, though), but your `operator+=` is not.

Your constructor and `operator+=` should look more like this instead:

```cpp
Ship::Ship(const char* type, const Engine engines[], int cnt){
    if (type != nullptr && engines != nullptr && cnt > 0) {
        // create a valid ship
        strncpy(m_type, type, TYPE_MAX_SIZE);
        if (cnt > NUM_OF_ENGINES) cnt = NUM_OF_ENGINES; // <-- ADD THIS LINE!
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
            m_engines[i] = engines[i];
        }        
        m_engCnt = cnt;
    }else{
        m_type[0] = '\0';
        m_engCnt = 0;
    }
}

Ship& Ship::operator+=(Engine e){
    if (!*this) {
        cout << "The Object is not valid! Engine cannot be added!" << endl;
        return *this;
    }else if (m_engCnt == NUM_OF_ENGINES){
        return *this;
    }else{
        m_engines[m_engCnt] = e; // <-- ADD THIS LINE!!!
        m_engCnt++;
        return *this;
    }    
}
```

I would suggest re-writing the constructor and `operator+=` to look more like this instead:

```cpp
Ship::Ship(const char* type, const Engine engines[], int cnt){
    strncpy(m_type, type != nullptr ? type : "", TYPE_MAX_SIZE);

    if (engines != nullptr && cnt > 0) {
        if (cnt > NUM_OF_ENGINES) cnt = NUM_OF_ENGINES;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
            m_engines[i] = engines[i];
        }        
        m_engCnt = cnt;
    }
    else
        m_engCnt = 0;
}

Ship& Ship::operator+=(const Engine &e){
    if (m_type[0] != '\0' && m_engCnt < NUM_OF_ENGINES) {
        m_engines[m_engCnt] = e;
        ++m_engCnt;
    }    
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I still need more practice with overloading operators, do you have any recommendations? Thanks it worked btw :)